# Adding system:time_start to a reduced modis collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, time-series

I need to add a system:time_start to a reduced modis collection. I am trying to get monthly maximum NDVI values but the system time start gets lost during the reducing processs and i am unsure of where to put the .copyProperties function. I need it for the chart. Here is my code:

```
var aoi = table

// Find MODIS NDVI images for relevant date range
var start_date = ee.Date("2012-05-05");
var end_date = ee.Date("2013-03-31");

var modis_filtered = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
                         .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                         .select("NDVI");

// Calculate monthly max NDVI values
var monthly_images = function(IC) {
    
  // Get number of months in interval
  var n_months = ee.List.sequence(0, end_date.difference(start_date, "month").round().subtract(1));
    
  // Iterate monthly max over all months in the interval
  var images = n_months.map(function(n) {
    
    // Get images for given month
    var start = start_date.advance(n, "month");
    var end = start.advance(1, "month");
    var filtered = IC.filterDate(start, end);

    var max = filtered.max()

    return max.set("month", start.get("month"), "year", start.get("year"));
    });
    
    return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images)

  
};


var ndvi_monthly_max = monthly_images(modis_filtered)

// Calculate average monthly cycle
var month_list = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var cycle = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(month_list.map(function(x) {
  return ndvi_monthly_max.filter(ee.Filter.eq("month", x))
                      .max()
                      .set("month", x)
                      
}));


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: ndvi_monthly_max, 
  region: aoi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250,
  
})
print(chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solution should work to add a "system"time_start" property to the ndvi_monthly_max collection. To my knowledge, `copyProperties()` would not work in this case for a couple reasons. First I don't think that function works for system properties, and second, because you are reducing the collection down to a maximum composite, not every pixel is coming from the same image so a system:time_start property would not be accurate for every pixel in the image.

For this case, I added a line in the monthly images function that pulls in the "system:time_start" property from the first image in the filtered collection. It should be noted however that this doesn't mean every pixel in the image was captured on that date, but should approximate the month/year well enough for what it sounds like you need.

```
var aoi = geometry

// Find MODIS NDVI images for relevant date range
var start_date = ee.Date("2012-05-05");
var end_date = ee.Date("2013-03-31");

var modis_filtered = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
                         .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                         .select("NDVI");
print(modis_filtered)

// Calculate monthly max NDVI values
var monthly_images = function(IC) {
    
  // Get number of months in interval
  var n_months = ee.List.sequence(0, end_date.difference(start_date, "month").round().subtract(1));
    
  // Iterate monthly max over all months in the interval
  var images = n_months.map(function(n) {
    
    // Get images for given month
    var start = start_date.advance(n, "month");
    var end = start.advance(1, "month");
    var filtered = IC.filterDate(start, end);

    var max = filtered.max()
    var first = filtered.first()

    return max.set("month", start.get("month"), 
                  "year", start.get("year"),
                  "system:time_start",first.get("system:time_start"));
    });
    
    return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images)

  
};

var ndvi_monthly_max = monthly_images(modis_filtered)


// Calculate average monthly cycle
var month_list = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var cycle = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(month_list.map(function(x) {
  return ndvi_monthly_max.filter(ee.Filter.eq("month", x))
                      .max()
                      .set("month", x)
                      
}));


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: ndvi_monthly_max, 
  region: aoi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 250,
  xProperty: "system:time_start"
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/341a49b9fb1dd586503313fd60a408b4

Comment: you will need to change the aoi variable back to your area of interest; I did not have access to your table.